# Inject a singleton with parameters

Tags: c#, ninject, inversion-of-control

Using Ninject, I have an interface that I want to bind to single instance of a concrete implementation. For example:

```
public interface IFoo { //... }
public class Foo { //... }
```

Now normally, I'd just bind something like this like so:

```
kernel.Bind<IFoo>().To<Foo>().InSingletonScope();
```

But, I need to add parameters to the constructor for `Foo`. Normally, again, that wouldn't be too much of a problem (I think):

```
kernel.Bind<IFoo>()
    .To<Foo>()
    .InSingletonScope()
    .WithConstructorArgument("bar", myBar);
```

Now the problem is that I can't know the value of `myBar` at the time I set up all my bindings. I need to defer that until the first time I need an `IFoo` (and note, in reality I have several arguments to pass). So what I need is a singleton, that will be lazy initialized on first use and only gets arguments at that point.

What's the best way to approach this? I'm assuming something with [Factory](http://www.planetgeek.ch/2011/12/31/ninject-extensions-factory-introduction/) is probably the solution, but I don't quite see the right way to do this. I don't want to create a *new* `Foo` every time.

Comment: can you not bind at any point in the program?

Comment: @Ewan: Not without passing the kernel around, which I don't want to do. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: it seems to me that your problem is 'the first time you need an IFoo' when you are talking about DI is not determinable. so how will you know that you know the construction parameters at that point?

Comment: no i agree passing the kernal around isnt a great solution. but you have an odd case

Comment: say I have some object which takes IFoo as a constructor parameter itself, how can you bind that, without having first bound IFoo?

Comment: @Ewan: Well I guess you can't, which is why it seems like it would make more sense to pass an `IFooFactory` and have that create your `IFoo`, but that seems like it might be beyond what `.ToFactory` can do. Or at least I can't see how that would work. I'd need it to generate a singleton factory.

Comment: personally i don't like the factory solution (bind a factory and call a createobj method) because it seems like you are duplicating the functionality of the di container. what about an Init(x,y,z) method on IFoo? throw an exception if you call its methods and its not been initialized?

Comment: @Ewan: That might work, let me think about that one for a while...

Comment: ooo ive got a better one. have Foo take a IInitializer constructor. when you call its method it calls the initalizer to try and get the required parameters and initialize itsself. you code can set these parameters on the initaliser whenever they become available. that way you avoid adding extra Foo specific stuff to IFoo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in my comment above. the real problem is that you may not have the construction parameters when you need Foo. In this pattern you can Bind all your interfaces as you please and call IInitialiser.Initialise when you are ready (obvs you need to keep a reference or make it static).

Foo will throw an exception if you call it before its been properly set up

IFoo remains unchanged

IInitialiser implementations can be tweaked to poll a DB or respond to events or whatever suits your late configuration senario best

```
using System;

namespace UnitTestProject3
{
    public interface IFoo
    {
        int GetAllTheFoo();
    }

    public interface IInitialiser
    {
        void Initialise(int x);

        int GetX();

        bool IsReady { get; }
    }

    public class Foo : IFoo
    {
        private bool isInitalised;
        private int x;
        private IInitialiser i;
        public Foo(IInitialiser i)
        {
            this.isInitalised = false;
            this.i = i;
        }

        protected void Init()
        {
            if (this.isInitalised)
            {
                return;
            }
            else if (i.IsReady)
            {
                x = i.GetX();
                this.isInitalised = true;
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("you have not set x");
            }
        }

        public int GetAllTheFoo()
        {
            Init();
            return x;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Factory extension.

```
public interface IFooFactory
{
    IFoo CreateFoo(string bar);
    IFoo CreateFoo();
}

public interface IFoo
{
    string Bar { get; set; }
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }

    public Foo(string bar)
    {
        Bar = bar;
    }
}

kernel.Bind<IFoo>().To<Foo>().InSingletonScope();
kernel.Bind<IFooFactory>().ToFactory();

IFoo foo1 = fooFactory.CreateFoo("myBar");
IFoo foo2 = fooFactory.CreateFoo("myDifferentBar"); // value is basically ignored here
IFoo foo3 = fooFactory.CreateFoo();
```

This will always return the same instance of Foo. Of course if you call the paremeterless method first it will result in an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Given the other two answers, I could be completely missing the point of the question, but why would not something as simple as this work for you:

```
kernel.Bind<IFoo>().ToMethod(x => CreateFoo()).InSingletonScope();
```

`CreateFoo` will be responsible for constructing your single object with whatever set of parameters that you need. By the time `CreateFoo` is called you should already know what the parameters are.